# "noexcept" warning on VSO build when running gulp

Tags: tfs, msbuild, gulp, azure-devops

I'm recently enabled gulp running on my VSO build, but I see it outputs a bunch of warning on build, e.g.

```
'noexcept' used with no exception handling mode specified; termination on exception is not guaranteed. Specify /EHsc [xxxxx.WebClient\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
'noexcept' used with no exception handling mode specified; termination on exception is not guaranteed. Specify /EHsc [xxxxx.WebClient\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

How do I resolve these warning, or atleast disable them.

Comment: Are you using vNext build or XAML build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog provides detailed steps on adding gulp to Visual Studio Online XAML Builds, you can follow it to have a build added gulp: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2015/03/05/adding-gulp-to-visual-studio-online-builds.aspx

Summary of the blog:

"

You need to add a folder ‘js’ to your web application project, which will contain your client-side JavaScript code.

Then you need to configure gulp for your web application by adding 3 files to your Web Application project in order to invoke grunt/gulp/bower commands in pre and post build scripts:

•gulpfile.js: contains the gulp script describing all build tasks that need to be performed.

•package.json: contains the list package dependencies for the gulp script

•clientcompile.bat (note: you can also use PowerShell): batch script that install the dependency packages and then invokes the gulp command

After that, queue a build in VSO.

"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I had come across that post before and followed it, and I have gulp running, just I get those warnings - they don't fail the build but was hoping to resolve them regardless,